# OpenBSD NFS server with Linux NFS clients -- file size limit?

Tags: linux, openbsd, nfs, file-sharing

I've set up an NFS server on OpenBSD 4.9. The client is Arch Linux x86-64. The mount has no problems with small files but when trying to read large files (in the example, an 7.4G iso file) it will simply freeze. Any program that tries to read from it seems to just get stuck. For example I tried

```
hexdump -n 100 big.iso
```

and it ends up doing nothing. And I end up having to kill hexdump and I always have to force an unmount on the NFS mount.

I'm mounting it as so on Linux:

```
sudo mount -t nfs -o noatime,intr,vers=3 192.168.1.50:/home/shared /mnt
```

The OpenBSD /etc/exports file is as so:

```
/home/shared -alldirs -ro -mapall=remote -network=192.168.1.0 -mask=255.255.255.0
```

And I've checked and making a small text file in the shared directory can be be read from Linux. And the small text file and big iso file have the same permissions and owners.

Has anyone else had this problem? According to the man pages, OpenBSD's nfs server should implement NFSv3.

Answer (score 2):

I forced Linux to mount it using UDP instead of TCP and now everything seems to work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Usually when you are mounting BSD's exports on Linux you have to adjust the following:

```
mount -f nfs **-o rsize=1024,wsize=1024** bsdserver:/share /my/linux/directory
```

Otherwise it is slow as a hog...